# Reusing or appending the same TextViews, EditText boxes on next line in the same activity on pressing a button in android

Tags: android

Can i print or add a EditText box to the next line on pressing a button.

It looks like this now:

[EditText]

```
       [Button]
```

After pressing the button it should look like this:

[EditText]

[EditText]

[Button]

Answer (score 1):

You can add the EditText to your layout and set its visibility to hidden or gone. When the button is clicked simply set the visibility back to visible.

Comment: I want to use one EditText multiple times on the same activity without adding it to the layout. Is it possible ?

Comment: If you want to use an EditText in your activity you have to add it to the layout. Either declarative in the xml or programatically for example in the onCreate method. If you want to reuse the EditText, you have to remove from the layout and then add it at another position, bit I don't think it's possible to add it several times.